# How to capture enter key, using scanner as console input?

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I want to capture enter character in console. I am inputting 2 strings.

Case 1. removestudent(pressing enter) removes all the students from array list.

Case 2. removestudent student1 removes students1 from array list.

```
Scanner in=new Scanner();

type_op=in.next();

param=in.next();

if (type_op.equals("removestudent"))
{

    //Calling remove student function and passing param over here.

}
```

Now the case 2 works fine. However, for Case 1, I want param value to be null when user presses enter. I will then pass param as a null value to my remove function and delete all the students in the array list.

```
list1.clear();
```

Please help me in knowing how to get this enter key.

Comment: scanner.nextLine() can be used with size() or isEmpty() for this

Comment: scanner.nextLine() will not work as I am trying to display an output string when user presses enter i.e "Do you want to delete all the records(y/n)"

Comment: look at @niiraj874u's answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  For help formatting your posts, click on the big fat orange question mark in the editor.  Also, *always* be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 3):

You can read line and if line is blank, You can assume it is enter key.. like below code..

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String readString = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println(readString);
if (readString.equals(""))
    System.out.println("Enter Key pressed.");
if (scanner.hasNextLine())
    readString = scanner.nextLine();
else
    readString = null;
```

Comment: Yes this will definitely work. However, I am also trying to get input through param, if the user does not press enter.

Comment: When user presses enter this will be displayed "Do you want to delete all the records(y/n)"

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you

```
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
String readString = input.nextLine();
while(readString!=null) {
    System.out.println(readString);
    if (readString.equals(""))
        System.out.println("Read Enter Key.");
    if (input.hasNextLine())
        readString = input.nextLine();
    else
        readString = null;
}
```

Comment: Looks very much like the other answer, but with some variation in program flow, so I'm not voting to close.