# hasnext hang How can I correct this error

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String temp = "";
        String a ="";

        String[] New;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        //String s1 = new String(keyboard.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Please write your elements.");

        while(keyboard.hasNext()){          
            String currentString = keyboard.next();
            if(currentString.equals(" ")){
                System.out.println("Bye");
            }
            a += (currentString.charAt(0) + "").toUpperCase() + currentString.substring(1).toLowerCase()+",";
        }
        a = a.substring(0, a.length()-1);

        New = a.split(",");
        System.out.println("Your elements are" + Arrays.toString(New) + ".");

        for (int x = 1; x < New.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < New.length - x; y++) {
                if (New[y].compareTo(New[y + 1]) > 0) {
                    temp = New[y];
                    New[y] = New[y + 1];
                    New[y + 1] = temp;

                }
            }

        } for(int i=0;i<New.length;i++){
            System.out.println(New[i]);
        }
        /*System.out.println("In alphabethical order form is:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(New));*/

    }
}
```

hasnext in infinite loop ı have already search stackowerflow but answers cant fix the error.please help me.Here my codesPlease write your elements.

ıf ı press space and enter ı have a problem .

Bye
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at aa.Sort.main(Sort.java:38)

Comment: You should check the answers given here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194290/how-to-capture-enter-key-using-scanner-as-console-input>. Specially the one given by @niiraj874u.

Comment: java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=17][match valid=true][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\.][decimal separator=\,][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q?\E][infinity string=\Q?\E]
what is this ?

Comment: this codes output are:banana apple -->banana apple so loop never ends

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things. You should use `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()` instead of `hasNext()` and `next()`.

After changing that, your while loop never ends, because you just print `Bye` and continue looping. Add a `break` statement after you print `Bye`.

```
if(currentString.equals(" ")){
    System.out.println("Bye");
    break;
}
```

Comment: this code cant solve my problem. ı want to press enter and quit loop.but nextline also have same problem

Comment: Your code is currently checking for a " " which is a space. It works perfectly for that...

Comment: If you want to check for an `enter` key press use `if(currentString.equals("\r")){....}`

Comment: ı tried before but ı cant quit loop ı always quit loop with Ctrl+Z

Answer (score 0):

Reading from console is different from reading file. Reading from Console the program expects a Stream and it will wait for further Input.

When testing from file (still with System.in for the Scanner, using Java Program ) the hasNext() will return false at the end of the file as no further Input can be done.